# TInyOS 1.x Generating an error when compiling BLINK

Tags: java, c++, c, tinyos

root@everton-laptop:/opt/tinyos-1.x/apps/Blink# make pc

```
compiling Blink to a pc binary

ncc -o build/pc/main.exe -g -O0 -board=micasb -pthread -target=pc  -Wall -Wshadow    -DDEF_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x7d -Wnesc-all -fnesc-nido-tosnodes=1000 -fnesc-cfile=build/pc/app.c Blink.nc -lm 

In file included from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/packet_sim.h:55,
                 from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/nido.h:81,
                 from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/hardware.h:43,
                 from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/system/tos.h:144:
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:155: parse error before `struct'
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:156: parse error before `struct'
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:158: parse error before `struct'
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h: In function `TOS_MsgLength':
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:186: parse error before `TOS_Msg'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/hardware.h:116,
                 from /opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/system/tos.h:144:
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/eeprom.c: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/eeprom.c:115: warning: declaration of `length' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:158: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/platform/pc/eeprom.c:145: warning: declaration of `length' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-1.x/tos/types/AM.h:158: warning: location of shadowed declaration
make: *** [build/pc/main.exe] Error 1
```

Tried compiling BLink and i keep getting the above error and not sure what to do next. any help would be nice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the CVS repository for `tos/types/AM.h`, it looks like it's choking on the following code:

```
154: enum {
155:    MSG_DATA_SIZE = offsetof(struct TOS_Msg, crc) + sizeof(uint16_t), // 36 by default
156:    TINYSEC_MSG_DATA_SIZE = offsetof(struct TinySec_Msg, mac) + TINYSEC_MAC_LENGTH, // 41 by default
157:    DATA_LENGTH = TOSH_DATA_LENGTH,
158:    LENGTH_BYTE_NUMBER = offsetof(struct TOS_Msg, length) + 1,
159:    TINYSEC_NODE_ID_SIZE = sizeof(uint16_t)
160: };
```

The common item from lines 155, 156, and 158 are the `offsetof()` macro, which should be defined in `stddef.h` and which looks like should have been brought in by the `tos.h` before it causes `AM.h` to be included, so `offsetof()` should already be defined.

You might want to verify whether or not the compiler you're using has `offsetof()` properly defined  and/or why it's not available for use in `AM.h`. If necessary, you can probably define it yourself using a more or less usual implementation:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t) ( (char *)&((st *)(0))->m - (char *)0 ))  // stolen from Wikipedia
```

Comment: going to try upgrading the compiler and see if that would fix the issue